# What's the difference between "Update all" and "Get updates" in Microsoft App Store? - and "Open" vs "Get"?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-interface, windows-store

The current version of the Microsoft Store (running on Windows 10 21H2, if that matters) has two buttons that seemingly do the same thing:

- A hyperlink-style button labelled "Update all"
- A button-style button labelled "Get updates"

There's no tooltip text on either button.

What is the difference between them?

[image]

---

While browsing, another confusing UI appeared: some installed apps have "Open", "Update", and "Get" buttons - with no instruction or indication what "Get" does...

[image]

Comment: I can't be certain, but here are my inferences: the term "get" in the former case should mean "loading" the resources required or refreshing the list to reflect currency, whereas "update all" should initiate the actual update procedure.  In the case of the latter, "open" should launch the application as you have it currently installed, "update" is self-explanatory, and "get" (again, my conjecture), *could* possibly be a means of adding the application to your library (similar to how Google Play's PC website allows you to acquire an application and push an install to a device you specify?).

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bad design choice by Microsoft, but because you have pending updates the description for the `Get updates` button is not shown. I just updated all my apps and now my UI looks as shown below.

> Check for additional updates by clicking "Get updates"

is the official description by Microsoft.

[image: Get updates]

After clicking "Get updates", it proceeded to find new updates for apps and installed them.

Comment: _"Probably a bad design choice by Microsoft..."_ - about par for the course thesedays.